# How come ModelAndView only prints the first index of an list?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using Thymeleaf as UI Framework, Using Java for backend, and I am creating a rest web services. Using JAXB to unmarshal xml from a URL. I figured that my controller is messing something up and that's why I cant get my full list printed.

**XML**

```
<results>
    <rootNode>
        <node>1336</node>
        <state>CL</state>
        <time>0</time>
        <ip_addresses>
             <ip_address type="DOC">06:56:43.0</ip_address>
             <ip_address type="PE">06:56:43.0</ip_address>
        </ip_addresses>
        <lease_date>2017-01-25</lease_date>
    </rootNode>
</results>
```

**Controller**

After several tests I narrowed down that the cause of the problem is in my controller.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
JAXSample index;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getDetails(Info  info) throws MalformedURLException {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("getDetails");

    //JAXSample index = new JAXSample();
    readingXml cinfo = index.readXML(info.getInputMacAddress());
    model.addObject("cinfo", cinfo);


    System.out.println(cinfo.getip_Addresses().toString() + "FROM CONTROLLER");


    return model;
}

 //****Should be [06:56:43.0, 06:56:43.0] ******
 Output: [06:56:43.0, ] FROM FROM CONTROLLER
```

**JaxSample.class**

jaxb example found @[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278493/jaxb-unmarshalling-from-url)

```
public readingXml readXML(String MAC) throws MalformedURLException {
results customer = null;
 readingXml  = null;
  try {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(results.class);
      URL url = new URL("some type of url for xml page" + MAC);

      HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
      http.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
      InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      customer = (results) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
      List<readingXml> readingXml = customer.getReadingXml();
      readingXml = readingXmls.get(0);
  } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  return readingXml;
}
```

So for testing purposes I tried to print my list values out.

```
 System.out.println(readingXml.ip_Addresses().toString() + "FROM SAMPLE");
   //****Should be [06:56:43.0, 06:56:43.0] ******
  //output [06:56:43.0, ] FROM SAMPLE
```

BUT!! when I copy the **same exact code** into my **main.class** and do the same request.

```
  System.out.println(readingXml.ip_Addresses().toString() + "FROM MAINCLASS");
  //output [06:56:43.0, 06:56:43.0] FROM MAINCLASS
```

I get the values I want. Why is this not working the same in JAXB or my Controller?

Comment: What if you unrem the line with JAXSample instead of having it with @Autowired annotation in your controller `//JAXSample index = new JAXSample();`

Comment: Same results [first_IP, ]. At first I thought the "new" keyword was causing it to print 1 value. Thats why I implemented the autowire

Comment: maybe `model.addObject("cinfo", cinfo);` messes it up, because you output after that

Comment: serge, yup it is model.addObjejct("cinfo",cinfo); When I remove that line it works. If I remove that line how would I be able to add into model? Thanks you so much.

Comment: Maybe there is something with your web.xml? Can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691253/spring-using-modelandview-addobject

Comment: I don't have a web.xml, I figured out the problem. It is when I pass my input into my JAXB. It causes the problem because the passed params basically build my url. If I hard coded the url it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134781/discussion-between-mike-chun-and-serge).